# Constructing Wagtail admin menu: How to get/set menu items name?

Tags: python, wagtail

I am trying to customize the rendering of the admin menu in Wagtail via a hook, as described [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#construct-main-menu):

```
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def hide_explorer_menu_item_from_frank(request, menu_items):
  if request.user.username == 'frank':
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'explorer']
```

But I can't figure out, how to get/set the `name` attribute of the `menu_items` objects in my models (or wherever). My hacky solution for now is to go for the indices:

```
menu_items[:] = list(menu_items[i] for i in [0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

But that is less then ideal. Anyone?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here - the code above shows that the name attribute can be accessed as `item.name`, doesn't it?

Comment: It does and I see why my questions seems odd. But the item name "explorer" was not assigned by me. It is a Wagtail default for the site-tree navigation. So maybe my question is indeed twofold. A) How to set the name attribute for my menu items? B) How would I print out the above list comprehension, aka how to print to stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented under the `register_admin_menu_item` hook](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item), you can pass a `name` keyword argument to the `MenuItem` object when creating it:

```
MenuItem('Videos', reverse('videos'), name='videos')
```

If you don't pass a name, one is automatically created from the label.

To print out the names of the existing menu items:

```
print([item.name for item in menu_items])
```

Comment: Oh man. I feel stupid. Two times. I am all day in the documentary and I didn't read it. Sorry. And I have overlooked that `print` does actually write to the debugger output. I did not want to give the impression as if I have not spend time on my problem before asking. But I am afraid I did.